# SpriteKit Select Sprite node from CGPoint

Tags: sprite-kit, cgpoint

First post,

I'm in Apple's SpriteKit framework...(new programmer) and I have a bunch of nodes that are stationary. How do I select/grab a particular node if I know the coordinates (CGPoints)? I basically want to say, grab that node at (x,y) and do something with it (i.e. change color)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the CGPoint, you use the command `nodeAtPoint:` However, this command only returns the deepest descendant that intersects a point. If you have the possibility of having more than one node at your CGPoint, you should use the command `nodesAtPoint:` instead.

Read up on the details in the [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) - section titled **Determining If a Point Lies in a Node**.

** Update **

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(10, 10);
SKNode *myNode = [self nodeAtPoint:myPoint];
```

Where `self` either is or needs to be replaced with the parent node of the node you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, so nodeatPoint returns the actual sprite node? It's returning null when I use it, and I know my coordinates lie inside the node...hmm.